# Stopping execution of an Enumerator on client cancellation of chunked response

Tags: scala, playframework, amazon-s3, stream, playframework-2.2

In the simple case of proxying a download from S3 to the client, I'm having trouble dealing with client disconnections mid-download.

```
val enumerator = Enumerator.outputStream{ out =>

    val s3Object = s3Client.getObject(new GetObjectRequest(bucket, path))
    val in = new BufferedInputStream(s3Object.getObjectContent())
    val bufferedOut = new BufferedOutputStream(out)

    Iterator.continually(in.read).takeWhile(_ != -1).foreach(bufferedOut.write)

    in.close()
    bufferedOut.close()
}

Ok.chunked(enumerator.andThen(Enumerator.eof).withHeaders(
    "Content-Disposition" -> s"attachment; filename=${name}"
)
```

This works (mostly) beautifully as long as the client doesn't cancel the download before it completes. Otherwise, on cancellation the enumerator keeps filling up with data until the download from S3 is complete. Several cancelled downloads can hog quite a bit of resources.

Are there any better patterns that can prevent this from happening?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Move closing the `InputStream` into an `onDoneEnumerating` block, and use `Enumerator.fromStream` instead of `Enumerator.outputStream`:

```
val s3Object = s3Client.getObject(new GetObjectRequest(bucket, path))
val in = s3Object.getObjectContent()

val enumerator = Enumerator.fromStream(in).onDoneEnumerating {
  in.close()
}
```

`fromStream` reads chunks (8 KiB by default) at a time, so a `BufferedInputStream` is unnecessary.

Also, with `outputStream`, there is no way for the `Iteratee` to push back if it is slow to consume the data, which could result in a large amount of data (up to the size of the S3 object) buffering in memory. This is dangerous, because the application could run out of memory. With `fromStream`, the next read won't occur until the `Iteratee` is ready for more data.

Comment: FWIW, I don't believe onDoneEnumerating { in.close() } is necessary because Enumerator.fromStream already does that.